# Receiver antenna design for reading PIT tags implanted in snakes and reptiles

Tags: antenna, rfid, receiver, tag

I am talking to a local conservation outfit trying to replace active implantable radio tags with passive PIT tags (I do not know who the manufacturer is). These active tags are really tiny glass capsules with a small antenna sticking out of them and are primarily used to track their location.

Their main challenge is removing the active tags (implanted surgically) after approximately four months to replace the battery. The tags are then sent back for refurbishment. This insertion, removal, and refurbishment sequence is expensive and, more importantly, highly stressful for the animals. Once they locate the animal, they have a different device that records the habitat parameters and the location where it is found.

I was looking at replacing them with [these PIT tags](https://www.oregonrfid.com/products/hdx-pit-tags/12mm-hdx-pit-tag/) and was hoping someone here would be able to point me to resources on how to design a receiver antenna for reading these tags from about a distance of 2-3 meters. Also, the reader for the existing active tags has a beeping function that lets users know as they start getting nearer the tag, which is also a functionality I hope to replicate.

Any ideas and guidance in this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like they already make readers, and long range readers on that web site.  What is different about what you want to do vs what they already make?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're going to get that sort of range with those tags. Have a look at this: https://support.oregonrfid.com/support/solutions/articles/5000006214-expected-hdx-read-range

Comment: @GodJihyo thanks. it says that customer built antennas have gotten as much as two meters. I was hoping to build something on similar lines.

Comment: @electrophile It sounds like you are looking for something hand held, the 2 meter distance is probably going to be for a large stationary loop, and they were using the largest size (32mm) tags. Here's an article that talks about detection range that might be helpful: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6802374/

Comment: @GodJihyo Thank you! Would you be able to point me to resources where I can learn about designing such an antenna?